# Let $G$ be a group of order $24$, and $a^{2002}=a^n$, find value of $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $24$, and $a^{2002}=a^n$, where $a\in G$ and $0\lt n\lt 24$.
Then the value of $n$ is which among the following:
a) $4$, 
a) $6$, 
a) $8$, 
a) $10$.

The order $o(G)=24$, and for any element $a$ in group maximum value of its order ($o_a$) can be $24$, and minimum value =$1$.

So, does it state $o_a^{2002}= 
o_a^{24.k+r}= 
o_a^n, k,r \in \mathbb {N}$ for which possible value of $n$?
If correct, then do we need find for each possible value of $a$, the value of $n$?
If yes, then what should be a correct approach rather than just checking for $a=24$, which is shown elsewhere to yield answer $10$ by $24*83+10=2002$.

The approach of taking a single value for $o_a$ is not clear at all.

Comment: You already wrote it: $a^{2022} = a^{24*83 + 10} = (a^{24})^{83} \cdot a^{10} = (1_G)^{83} \cdot a^{10} = 1_G \cdot a^{10} = a^{10}$

Comment: @Jan issue is why need consider order of $a=24$, while there are many other elements with different orders.

Comment: I think a more general statement is not possible. Of course, if $a = 1_G$, then $a^{2022} = a^1 = a^0 = 1_G$. If $a$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z} / 24\mathbb{Z}$ then $n = 10$. The point is that $n = 10$ is always true, the other options might be true depending on the group $G$ and the element $a \in G$ but not in general (I have given you a counterexample already)

Comment: As I say, if you do not have further information about the group or the element $a \in G$, $n= 10$ is all you can say. Of course you can calculate $n$ depending on the order of $a$. Possible orders of $a$ are $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24\}$. In these cases $n$ would be given by $(0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 2, 10, 10)$ if I did not make any mistake. Also I realized that I wrote 2022 instead of 2002 in the above comments. sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2002=83(24)+10$ is indeed true, you are correct that

$$\begin{align}
a^{2002}&=a^{83(24)+10}\\
&=a^{83(24)}a^{10}\\
&=(a^{24})^{83}a^{10}\\
&=e^{83}a^{10}\\
&=ea^{10}\\
&=a^{10}.
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $n=10$.

You are correct that $24m+10$ will also do for any $m\in\Bbb Z$, but since none of these is between $0$ and $24$ for $m\neq 83$, we can select $n=10$.

Comment: FYI the "true" reason for why $n = 10$ is the only correct answer is because of the condition $0 < n < 24$.

Comment: I thought that was implied, @GarethMa, but I have edited my answer accordingly; thank you.